# Getting error: A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property

Tags: c#, constructor

**The error message was**:

```
Error   1   A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'AmazingPaintball.Form1.thePoint'
```

This is the constructor:

```
namespace AmazingPaintball
{
class Paintball
{
    public Point startPoint;


    public Paintball(Point myPoint)
    {
        startPoint = myPoint;


    }
```

This is the code that causes the error:

```
    Point thePoint = new Point(50, 50);
    Paintball gun = new Paintball(thePoint);
```

Comment: Where is the code that gave the error? Is it in a method?

Answer (score 7):

You haven't shown enough context, but I suspect you've got something like:

```
class Game
{
    Point thePoint = new Point(50, 50);
    Paintball gun = new Paintball(thePoint);
}
```

As the compiler says, a field initializer can't refer to another field or an instance member. The solution is simple though - put the initialization in the constructor:

```
class Game
{
    Point thePoint;
    Paintball gun;

    public Game()
    {
        thePoint = new Point(50, 50);
        gun = new Paintball(thePoint);
    }
}
```

That's assuming you really *need* both fields, mind you. If you only actually need a `gun` field, you can use:

```
class Game
{
    Paintball gun = new Paintball(new Point(50, 50));
}
```

(As an aside, I'd strongly advise against variable names beginning with `the`. The prefix doesn't add any extra information... it's just noise.)

Comment: Maybe the variable represents "thePoint" of a conversation :)

Comment: *I'd strongly advise against variable names beginning with the.* Maybe there's a method `GetTo`  that accepts a point.